# Mini slayer exciter (tesla coil) not working

Tags: tesla-coil

I recently built this tesla coil, and I've tried many different setups, but for some reason, I can't quite figure out why it won't work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqZJR1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I also have a few pictures that I took to show what I have. The 9volt is charged. I double checked the leads on the transistor, I don't know what could be causing the problem.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

[image: image4]

The last picture is before I added the 2 rectifier diodes.

Comment: I am uncertain of intended action BUT -  Polarity of secondary to primary matters. D1 D2 need to conduct when secondary "fires". If my understanding of ooperation is correct - transistor base is driven negative when firing - so BOTTOM of primary winding shoukld go to transistor collector. You have TOP going to collector.

Comment: Here is coil that someone else built: https://www.instructables.com/id/Slayer-Exciter-Circuit-Poor-Mans-Tesla-Coil/  It seems to be basically the same as yours. The coil polarities are critical.

Comment: Your solder joints are terrible. Copper oxidizes and will not solder well. Use fine sandpaper or a knife to scrape the oxidation away until the copper is bright and shiny before you solder.

Comment: The 47K should go from base tp V+ ||| In your modified circuit you failed to keep the base to +ve resistor where it belongs. You now have it going from base to collector - as soon as the transistor starts to turn on it reduces base drive and the transistor enters a stable low current state.

Comment: Is the copper wire that you are using "insulated" ? ie has it got a thin coating (enamel or similar) on it that prevents electrical contact being made when you touch anything to the wire. The wire MUST be insulated.

Comment: **IS THE WIRE INSULATED?**

Comment: No, but its not touching the secondary coil. I have it hot-glued in place, and at no point is it in contact with teh secondary coil.

Answer (score 3):

Polarity of secondary to primary matters.
D1 D2 need to conduct when secondary "fires".
Transistor base is driven negative when firing -
so BOTTOM of primary winding should go to transistor collector.
You have TOP going to collector.

Swap connections to primary winding.
Stand clear.

**______________________________________**

Added:

The 47K should go from base to V+

In your modified circuit you failed to keep the base to +ve resistor where it belongs. You now have it going from base to collector - as soon as the transistor starts to turn on it reduces base drive and the transistor enters a stable low current state.

Comment: I have performed the revision, but still not lighting up the light bulb. This is how it looks after revision. https://imgur.com/uclbsVA Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, when I swapped the leads of the top and bottom of the primary coil, i forgot to switch over the resistor to the V+. I've done that now, and it still doesn't work. I'm starting to think I may have fried something along the way, because now everything should be correct but the light bulb isn't responding. https://imgur.com/rpMTxlN

Comment: @Anhedonian A dead transistor is the most likely thing - but it shouldn't have been killed by what you did. Check your solder joints are OK (they are less pretty than they could be. And general layout could easily be quite a lot tidier. | [TIP31C datasheet here](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/a2/01/d8/6b/ba/9d/49/86/CD00104632.pdf/files/CD00104632.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00104632.pdf) - The current gain is low - 10 to about 50 depending on colour grouping.  ...

Comment: ... Base current via the 47k is about 0.15 mA (SMALL!) so collector current is about 1.5 mA (tiny) to under 10 mA (still tiny). I'd think a 4k7 base resistor or even smaller would be in order. | What is your MEASURED battery voltage?

Comment: I dont have a voltmeter so i dont know, but im using a standard duracell 9v. I swapped 47k resistor to a 20k resistor, and I also swapped the 2 rectifier diodes to an LED diode. The LED isn't lighting up, but I can feel the transistor starting to get kinda warm. Still no light bulb response. I moved the setup to a breadboard for a clean solder-free circuit haha, here is how it looks now https://imgur.com/uPTrZmd I KNOW the circuit is right, but for some reason, I'm not getting a reaction

Comment: @Anhedonian If you KNOW the circuit is right then it MUST be working and you don't need any help from here. Right :-) ?  | I suggested 4k7 or smaller. You have used 20k which is ! 4 x larger. | LED is valid BUT whereas we could see diode polarity at a glance that has now added another uncertainty - polarity is vital. | The LED MAY never light - it conducts when the secondary is driven - this will be at low current and probably VERY short duration. |

Comment: @Anhedonian  A voltmeter (usually one function of a digital multimeter) is such an utterly vital tool and costs from less (probably) than the components for this one circuit that you must have one. | Where are you located? 
| [Multimeters under about $US5 - free shipping](http://bit.ly/2VOXC52) |

Comment: I'm here because the circuit is right, and its not working, and im hoping someone can tell me why. This is my first electrical project so I dont have all the tools, but i finally got my hands on a multimeter, my battery is putting out 8.13V, I used a 5.1k resister and a 2k resistor, diode still not lighting, and still no bulb response. I put the long end of diode (+) to the emitter and shorter end (-) going to the base. Transister got hotter quicker with the 2k resistor, as expected, but still no response (bulb or led) other than heating transistor.